# Can you calculate confidence intervals for the population mean if the obtained sample is not normally distributed?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

From my knowledge, if the obtained sample is approximately normally distributed, we can use t-tables to calculate the population mean confidence interval without knowing the population standard deviation.

However is there a way to calculate the population mean confidence interval if the obtained sample is not normally distributed??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

First, in many cases, the sample is not normally distributed but you can use the central limit theorem to make a normal approximation and obtain an asymptotical confidence interval.

But you can also find exact confidence intervals even if the data is not normal. You need to find a pivotal quantity, i.e. a statistic whose distribution does not depend on the parameter of the underlying distribution.

For example let $X_1,\dots,X_n\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda)$. We have $\lambda\bar{X}\sim \Gamma(n,n)$. Thus we have :
$$P\left(\frac{u_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{\bar{X}}\leq\lambda\leq\frac{u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{\bar{X}}\right)=1-\alpha$$
where $u_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ and $u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ are the quantiles of $\Gamma(n,n)$ with levels $\frac{\alpha}{2}$ and $1-\frac{\alpha}{2}$.